# How to connect blockchains with Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

How can we connect multiple blockchains in Hyperledger Fabric like sidechains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current implementation lacks clarity on this subject but it could be fairly easy implemented into a smart contract whose responsibility was to e.g. sign a document in another blockchain db. So one could simply use the REST API for the other network in Go Lang